# How to remove the save and cancel buttons from Custom SharePoint List form(New form)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form, sharepoint-server, list-form

I want to add a custom webpart on a custom list form and remove the **Save** and **Cancel** buttons which are default. Is what i'm trying to do possible? If yes please tell me a good approach to do it?

Thanks.........

Answer (score 4):

One way at least is to use this CSS:

```
.ms-formtoolbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is for 2013, and `ListFormWebPart` (I'm guessing you might be using both 2013 and this Web Part)

Comment: i want to access something like the codebehind of the default save and cancel buttons? Is it possible?

Comment: If you have a completely custom form, then you should be able to edit the XSLT and just remove the buttons from there

Comment: say if i hide the default save button by the code which you have mentioned and add a visual webpart on that form which has a save button by itself then will any event receiver related to the list run when i click on my custom save button?

Comment: That does sound like a horrible solution, but yes in theory that should work. Any button of type submit on the page should trigger a postback which should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

no, this code hide all bottons...

this is what you need i think

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
var x=document.getElementsByTagName(“input”);
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
 {
 if (x.item(i).type==”button”&&x.item(i).value==”Save and Close”)
 {x.item(i).style.display = “none”};
 }
</script>

<div style="padding-left:5px">
</ContentTemplate>
```

in newform.aspx and editform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the page by appending "&toolpaneview=2" , this will open the page in edit mode. Now hide the default webpart and add your custom webpart.

Answer (score 0):

Create New and Edit forms in SharePOint Designer and change the ms-toolbar to ms-hidden.

This works for all fields

```
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-hidden" nowrap="nowrap">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                    <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="ms-separator">&#160;</td>
                    <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton1"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```